# Redirection sytnax

Tags: regex, .htaccess

A website I'm working on will use various paths to images, which in fact will be stored in one common folder.
I want all requests matching a specified pattern to be successful and display the requested image.

My matching criteria pattern is as follows:

```
"/" + any web-friendly path (could include forward slashes) + "_" + 6 digit number + "_" + one of the following: [tn|s|m|l|xl|xxl] + ".jpg"
```

Then if a request is matching the pattern it should be redirected like so:

```
"/img/" + requested 6 digit number + "_" + requested characters from [tn|s|m|l|xl|xxl] + ".jpg".
```

So everything (including first part of the requested filename) directly in front of 6 digit number should be replaced with "/img/".

Some examples:

```
/foo/bar_000001_s.jpg                 -> /img/000001_s.jpg
/foo/bar/foo-foo_bar-bar_000099_s.jpg -> /img/000099_s.jpg
```

My closest attempt:

```
RewriteRule ^\/([A-Za-z0-9_-\/\s]+)_([0-9]{6})_([tn|s|m|l|xl|xxl])(.jpg)$ /img/$2_$3$4$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```
RewriteRule (?:^|/)[\w-]+?_(\d{6})_(tn|[sml]|xx?l)(\.jpg)$ /img/$1_$2$3 [L,NC,R=302]
```

- Make starting `/` optional
- Use `\w` for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- Make first match non-greedy using `+?`
- For alternation remove `[` and `]` and clean it up
- Remove `$` from end of target URI

Comment: Hello @anubhava thank you for your reply. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working for me, does [\w-] include forward slashes? Did you mean "$1" instead of "12" in "img/12_$2$3"?

Comment: Thank you for updated answer, I really appreciate it, but unfortunately I still can't get it to work.

Comment: For which URL it didn't work? Do you have other rules also in same .htaccess, if yes then this rule should be topmost rule.